# c#: How to parse & validate datetime string that has auto-generated format

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, parsing

I am generating a string datetime value using:

```
string str = DataTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

this gives out "09/22/2020 5:30:01 PM" as per my existing local machine settings.

In my ui I edit it to :
string bad_year = "09/22/202 5:30:01 PM";

Now, when i am trying to parse/validate it using:

```
var style = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces;
var cul = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTime.TryParse(bad_year, cul, style, out dt_out);
```

dt_out gives: 09/22/0202 5:30:01 PM

I *expect* the dt_out to be null as it has wrong year in it.  Any idea?  Thanks a lot.

(Here, if we chose to use DateTime.TryParseExact(..) then we have to supply the format which i don't want to do explicitly and it should be automatically picked up from current CultureInfo) )

Comment: **`dt_out` cannot be `null`** because `DateTime` is a value-type, not a reference-type. Also to check if the string is actually valid you need to check the `Boolean` return value from `TryParse`, not the value of `dt_out` (`dt_out` should be disregarded if `TryParse` returns `false`).

Comment: So change your code to `if( DateTime.TryParse( ..., out DateTime parsed ) )`. and only look at `parsed` inside the `if` block.

Comment: @Dai: Thanks .. I tried  var b = DateTime.TryParse(bad_year, c, e, out dt_out);  // but the b is true here still !!

Comment: The year 202 is a valid year, so `b` will obviously be `true`. It is a valid date.

Comment: Thanks. True, i think i have to check for the year as mentioned below, rest all args will return false if wrong/out-of-range.

Comment: Maybe `DateTime.TryParseExact` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what tried, you may need additional check to see if the century is sensible in the context of the application you are building

```
public static void Main()
{
    DateTime dt_out; 
    var style = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None;
    var cul = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    //string good_year = "03/01/2009 10:00 AM";
    string bad_year = "22/03/202 05:30:01 PM";
    
    
      // Attempt to convert a string.      
      if (DateTime.TryParse(bad_year, cul, style, out dt_out))
           if(dt_out.Year <= 1900 || dt_out.Year >= 2100)
           {                                
                // Date is parsed successfully but not possible in my business context
                dt_out = DateTime.MinValue;
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert {0} to a date and time.", dt_out);
           }
           else 
           {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} converted to {1} {2}.",dt_out, dt_out, dt_out.Kind);
           }
      else
         Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert {0} to a date and time.", dt_out);
}
```

Also DateTime is a struct type means it can't be null. From the docs
" The MinValue and MaxValue properties can be used to ensure that a value lies within the supported range before passing it to a DateTime constructor.  "
or you can test your own custom date range.
Hope that helps.